# Python IDLE crash on mac Snow Leopard

Tags: python, macos, crash, osx-snow-leopard, python-idle

I have a Mac OS X 10.6 64bit,
the problem is simple:

When I try to run something on the Python IDLE, it crashes. It crashes also when I try simply to copy/paste something.

It's happening with all python versions I've tried: 2.5 2.6 2.7 and 3.3.
I avoided this problem by using another IDE and running on it but it is not a solution.
Thanks

Comment: Have you followed these instructions: https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/? Beyond that, you've provided nowhere near enough information to make sensible suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes I have had this problem if I try to run the IDLE directly. Try calling the IDLE from python itself. Do this by creating a file containing:

```
    from idlelib.PyShell import main
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

save it as like run_idle.py then you can run the command: 
        python run_idle.py

This will open up the IDLE that is appropriate to the version of python installed on your system. I also use this technique to successfully run the IDLE within a virtual environment.

Comment: Calling idlelib.PyShell.main() is an implementation detail that could change in the future. `import idlelib.idle` directly starts Idle and should always do so.